# elasticsearch - there is no copy of the shard available?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a few indices in red, after a failure of the system, caused by disk full.
But I cannot reallocate the lost shard. It says "there is no copy of the shard available"

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain?pretty'
{
  "shard" : {
    "index" : "my_index",
    "index_uuid" : "iNY9t81wQf6wJc-KqufUrg",
    "id" : 0,
    "primary" : true
  },
  "assigned" : false,
  "shard_state_fetch_pending" : false,
  "unassigned_info" : {
    "reason" : "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
    "at" : "2017-05-30T07:33:04.192Z",
    "failed_attempts" : 5,
    "delayed" : false,
    "details" : "failed to create shard, failure FileSystemException[/data/es/storage/nodes/0/indices/iNY9t81wQf6wJc-KqufUrg/0/_state/state-13.st.tmp: Read-only file system]",
    "allocation_status" : "deciders_no"
  },
  "allocation_delay_in_millis" : 60000,
  "remaining_delay_in_millis" : 0,
  "nodes" : {
    "KvOd2vSQTOSgjgqyEnOKpA" : {
      "node_name" : "node1",
      "node_attributes" : { },
      "store" : {
        "shard_copy" : "NONE"
      },
      "final_decision" : "NO",
      "final_explanation" : "there is no copy of the shard available",
      "weight" : -3.683333,
      "decisions" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has already failed allocating [5] times vs. [5] retries allowed unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2017-05-30T07:33:04.192Z], failed_attempts[5], delayed=false, details[failed to create shard, failure FileSystemException[/data/es/storage/nodes/0/indices/iNY9t81wQf6wJc-KqufUrg/0/_state/state-13.st.tmp: Read-only file system]], allocation_status[deciders_no]] - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry"
        }
      ]
    },
    "pC9fL41xRgeZDAEYvNR1eQ" : {
      "node_name" : "node2",
      "node_attributes" : { },
      "store" : {
        "shard_copy" : "AVAILABLE"
      },
      "final_decision" : "NO",
      "final_explanation" : "the shard cannot be assigned because one or more allocation decider returns a 'NO' decision",
      "weight" : -2.333333,
      "decisions" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has already failed allocating [5] times vs. [5] retries allowed unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2017-05-30T07:33:04.192Z], failed_attempts[5], delayed=false, details[failed to create shard, failure FileSystemException[/data/es/storage/nodes/0/indices/iNY9t81wQf6wJc-KqufUrg/0/_state/state-13.st.tmp: Read-only file system]], allocation_status[deciders_no]] - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry"
        }
      ]
    },
    "1g7eCfEQS9u868lFSoo7FQ" : {
      "node_name" : "node3",
      "node_attributes" : { },
      "store" : {
        "shard_copy" : "AVAILABLE"
      },
      "final_decision" : "NO",
      "final_explanation" : "the shard cannot be assigned because one or more allocation decider returns a 'NO' decision",
      "weight" : 40.866665,
      "decisions" : [
        {
          "decider" : "max_retry",
          "decision" : "NO",
          "explanation" : "shard has already failed allocating [5] times vs. [5] retries allowed unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2017-05-30T07:33:04.192Z], failed_attempts[5], delayed=false, details[failed to create shard, failure FileSystemException[/data/es/storage/nodes/0/indices/iNY9t81wQf6wJc-KqufUrg/0/_state/state-13.st.tmp: Read-only file system]], allocation_status[deciders_no]] - manually call [/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true] to retry"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried basically every option of the `reroute` command (documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html)). but it gives me 400 error.. like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "commands" : [

        {
          "allocate_replica" : {
                "index" : "myindex", "shard" : 0,
                "node" : "node2"
          }
        }
    ]
}'
```

response:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "[allocate_replica] trying to allocate a replica shard [myindex][0], while corresponding primary shard is still unassigned"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "[allocate_replica] trying to allocate a replica shard [myindex][0], while corresponding primary shard is still unassigned"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

curl -XPOST 'xx.xxx.xx:9200/_cluster/reroute' -d '{"commands" : [{"allocate_stale_primary":{"index" : "myindex", "shard" : 0, "node" : "node2","accept_data_loss" : true}}]}'